# PyQt5 - QThread & QTimer - Why do they interfere?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have two Python modules each containing one timer.

The first module reads from joystick:

```py
# QThrottle.py
from dataclasses import dataclass

import pygame
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QTimer, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal


@dataclass
class JData:
    # 7 axes
    axis = [0.0] * 7
    # 16 buttons
    btn = [0] * 16


class QThrottle(QObject):
    # signals
    axis_changed = pyqtSignal([int, float])
    button_changed = pyqtSignal([int, int])

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QThrottle, self).__init__(parent)

        # container to store last data to compare them with the new ones
        self.j_data = JData()

        pygame.joystick.init()

        # sim_timer to run the simulator
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer_start()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_timer_timeout(self):
        # only continue if one device is plugged in
        if pygame.joystick.get_count() < 1:
            return

        # only one joystick is foreseen here
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        joystick.init()

        # check all axes for changes
        def check_axes(id):
            val = joystick.get_axis(id)
            if self.j_data.axis[id] != val:
                self.axis_changed.emit(id, val)
                self.j_data.axis[id] = val
        num_axes = range(joystick.get_numaxes())
        # list(map(check_axes, num_axes))

        # check all buttons for changes
        def check_buttons(id):
            val = joystick.get_button(i)

            if self.j_data.btn[i] != val:
                # print('button {id}: {val}'.format(id=i, val=val))
                self.button_changed.emit(i, val)
                self.j_data.btn[i] = val
        num_buttons = range(joystick.get_numbuttons())
        # list(map(check_buttons, num_buttons))

    def timer_start(self):
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timer_timeout)
        # set the refresh time
        self.timer.start(1)

    def timer_stop(self):
        self.timer.timeout.disconnect(self.on_timer_timeout)
        self.timer.stop()
```

The second module currently simulates some serial inputs:

```py
# QCom.py
from math import cos, sin, pi

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QTimer, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class QCom(QObject):
    # signals
    received_val1 = pyqtSignal(float)
    received_val2 = pyqtSignal(float)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QCom, self).__init__(parent)
        # first variables
        self.counter = 0

        # sim_timer to run the simulator
        self.sim_timer = QTimer()

    # ##### Simulator #####
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_timer_timeout(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.counter %= 360
        self.received_val1.emit(50 + 50 * sin(self.counter * pi / 180))
        self.received_val2.emit(50 + 50 * cos(self.counter * pi / 180))

    def sim_start(self):
        self.sim_timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timer_timeout)
        self.sim_timer.start(10)

    def sim_stop(self):
        self.sim_timer.timeout.disconnect(self.on_timer_timeout)
        self.sim_timer.stop()
```

The main loads the two modules, the qml-fronend and a qml-backend:

```py
# main.py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from QCom import QCom
from QThrottle import QThrottle

from QmlWindow.MainWindowBackend import MainWindowBackend

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    # Create an instance of the application
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    thread_com = QThread(app)
    thread_com.start()
    com = QCom()
    com.moveToThread(thread_com)
    com.sim_start()

    thread_throttle = QThread(app)
    thread_throttle.start()
    throttle = QThrottle()
    throttle.moveToThread(thread_throttle)

    # Create QML engine
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    # Create a window object
    backend = MainWindowBackend()
    # And register it in the context of QML
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", backend)
    # Load the qml file into the engine
    engine.load('QmlWindow/MainWindow.qml')

    com.received_val1.connect(backend.received_val1.emit)
    com.received_val2.connect(backend.received_val2.emit)

    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The QML stuff seems not important here.

At the beginning I load both modules this way:

```py
    com = QCom()
    throttle = QThrottle()
```

and I observed even on low timer frequencies some jerking movements at my qml frontend. And this is despite the fact that there is no connection between QCom and QML via signals.

I thought maybe it would be better to run both modules in separate threads and made the following change:

```py
    thread_com = QThread(app)
    thread_com.start()
    com = QCom()
    com.moveToThread(thread_com)
    com.sim_start()

    thread_throttle = QThread(app)
    thread_throttle.start()
    throttle = QThrottle()
    throttle.moveToThread(thread_throttle)
```

I checked with `QThread.currentThreadId()` inside `on_timer_timeout()` to see if the handlers were running on separate threads and they were. But the jerking remained. It seemed to me, that both timers interfere. But I expected that should not be the case if both of them run in different threads.

How can this be fixed?

---

The QML part:

```py
# MainWindowBackend.py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class MainWindowBackend(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    # Signals which shall be handled by qml
    # corresponding slots are implemented in MainWindow.qml -> appWindow -> Connections
    # the preferred argument name shall be 'val' to ease handling
    received_val1 = pyqtSignal(float, arguments=['val'])
    received_val2 = pyqtSignal(float, arguments=['val'])
```

```
// MainWindow.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow

    visible: true
    title: "MyPanel"
    property int margin: 11
    width: mainLayout.implicitWidth + 2 * margin
    height: mainLayout.implicitHeight + 2 * margin
    minimumWidth: mainLayout.Layout.minimumWidth + 2 * margin
    minimumHeight: mainLayout.Layout.minimumHeight + 2 * margin

    ColumnLayout {
        id: mainLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: appWindow.margin

        RowLayout {
            id: eLayout
            EBox {
                eId: "1"
                id: e1Box
            }
            EBox {
                eId: "2"
                id: e2Box
            }
        }
    }

    // connect backend to boxes (eng 1 & 2)
    // the slot on Python side:  mySlot
    // corresponds to qml side:  onMySlot
    Connections {
        target: backend

        onReceived_val1: { e1Box.eng = val }
        onReceived_val2: { e2Box.eng = val }
    }
}
```

```
// EBox.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


GroupBox {
    property string eId: "n"
    title: "Dev " + eId

    // properties which are intended to be connected to the backend
    property double eng: 08.15

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.minimumWidth: egauge.width
            Layout.minimumHeight: egauge.height
            Layout.preferredWidth: 200
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100

            StdGauge {
                id: egauge
                value: eng
                label: "Unit"
                title: "Title"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// StdGauge.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


CircularGauge {
    id: cgauge
    value: 0
    property string label: ""
    property string title: ""
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Rectangle {
        id: display
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 0.4*(parent.width<parent.height?parent.width:parent.height)
        height: width
        color: "black"
        border.color: "gray"
        border.width: 3
        radius: width*0.5
        Text {
            id: dispValue
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pointSize: 16
            font.bold: true
            color: "gray"
            text: cgauge.value.toFixed(2)
        }
        Text {
            id: dispLabel
            anchors.top: dispValue.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: dispValue.horizontalCenter
            font.pointSize: 10
            font.bold: true
            color: "gray"
            text: cgauge.label
        }
    }
    Text {
        id: dispTitle
        anchors.top: display.bottom
        anchors.bottom: cgauge.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: cgauge.horizontalCenter
        font.pointSize: 16
        font.bold: true
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        color: "gray"
        text: cgauge.title
    }
}
```

---

PS:

I am aware of, that the call

```py
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        joystick.init()
```

in `on_timer_timeout` is time-consuming and should be solved in a more elegant way. But this is not the focus of this question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "jerking". And I'm also not so sure I can understand what you're trying to achieve here. Consider that QTimer does *not* call its timeout slots precisely at the interval set for it: it only *tries* to do so, as long as the event loop allows: if you have an interval of 10ms and the connected function requires 15ms, the next timeouts will be called after 15ms; That said, a 1ms timer is very low interval, are you sure about that?

Comment: I mean the movement of a gauge (qml), displaying the values coming from the simulator, is not smooth.
The behaviour of QTimer is clear to me and it is ok then it takes some time more than whished. But I do not understand why a callback at QCom, which takes to much time, interferes with the callback in QThrottle.
The intention of the code is, that I have a bunch of interface modules, gathering data from different devices, and one qml-front-end to display all these.

Comment: @Alex44 please provide a [mre](share the .qml)